# Trying to figure out if two functions contradict the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

My functions are $f(x)=3x^4-2x^3-x^2+1$ and $g(x)=4x^3-3x^2-2x$ viewed on [0,1]. I had to show that there is no $\bar{x}$ in (0,1) such that $\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{g(1)-g(0)}=\frac{f'(\bar{x})}{g'(\bar{x})}$. I did that and now have to answer why that does not contradict the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem. Is the answer because the functions are not differentiable at [0,1] when looking on a graph?

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy's MVT guarantees the existence of some $\bar x \in (0, 1)$ such that:
$$
g'(\bar{x})[f(1)-f(0)] = f'(\bar{x})[g(1)-g(0)]
$$
Indeed, we can solve this equation for $\bar x$ to obtain:
$$
\bar x \in \left\{ 0, \underbrace{\frac{3 + \sqrt{33}}{12}}_{0.7287\ldots}, \underbrace{\frac{3 - \sqrt{33}}{12}}_{-0.2287\ldots
} \right\}
$$
Hence, we have that:
$$
\bar x = \frac{3 + \sqrt{33}}{12}
$$
However, this solution does not work for the original equation because by coincidence, we have that $g'(\bar x) = 0$.

Comment: How did get g'($\bar{x}$) = 0 because I got it to equal -1.

Comment: @ematth7: Well, $g'(x) = 12x^2 - 6x - 2$ and here's what Wolfram|Alpha computes: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=12(%5Cfrac%7B3+%2B+%5Csqrt%7B33%7D%7D%7B12%7D)%5E2+-+6(%5Cfrac%7B3+%2B+%5Csqrt%7B33%7D%7D%7B12%7D)+-+2